# Prevent/override standard Modal Dialog close button(X) from closing

Tags: javascript, client-object-model, jquery, list-form, modal-dialog

I want to validate custom modal dialog form and if its not ok, prevent form from closing.
For this purpose, I attached to X-close-dialog-button. Problem is to prevent it's default behavior.

```
function fValidateBeforeClose(event) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation(); // Not working
}    
function fAddOnCloseHandler() {
    var oCloseButton = jQuery("a[id^='DlgClose']", parent.document);
    oCloseButton.on( "click", function (event) { fValidateBeforeClose(event)} ); 
}       
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push( ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(fAddOnCloseHandler, "SP.js") );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Good way to remove handlers from dialog's close button is using [$clearHandlers Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310959%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Check code below:

```
function fValidateBeforeClose(event) {
    var isValid = true;
    //set IsValid value
    if(isValid)
    {
       //close dialog
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().close();
    }
    else
    {
      alert('Not valid');
    }
}  

function fAddOnCloseHandler() {
    var oCloseButton = $("a[id^='DlgClose']");

    $clearHandlers(oCloseButton.get(0));

    $(oCloseButton).on("click", function (event) { fValidateBeforeClose(event)} );
}   

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push( ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(fAddOnCloseHandler, "SP.js") );
```

Comment: Worked. I modify your answer, to remove unnecessary element search in DOM.

Comment: Ok, I approved it.

Answer (score 3):

In SharePoint 2013, this works fine after I added "`window.parent.document`" in the following line:

```
var oCloseButton = $("a[id^='DlgClose']",window.parent.document);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should remove old event handler

```
 var js = oCloseButton.attr("onclick");
 oCloseButton.attr("onclick", "");//remove sharepoint click handler...
```

Comment: Good catch,`jQuery(oCloseButton).off().find("*").off();` seems working. Though, I liked "the SharePoint way" provided by @Andrew better.